# Unity3D invisible Canvas performance

Tags: android, ios, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a 2d menu heavy mobile game, which uses a lot of canvases, panels, popups etc. In the beginning I had all menus active at all times, but only the ones that the user can use lie within the frustum (i.e. the others are just translated out of sight). Then I switched to deactivating the menus that the user can't see, just to increase the game performance. This however causes many inconveniences for me, like e.g. state variables in the Animator component resetting when de- and reactivating a GameObject.

So what is the best way to do this? Is the deactivation of temporarily unused canvases even worth it, or is Unity automatically clipping away the UI that lies out of the frustum, so there's basically no performance cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said your game is menu heavy, even disabling/enabling can cause overhead. This is something I have faced this in one of my projects in past.

A word of advice is to use [Canvas Group](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html) on your menu objects and change their alpha (0 = closed, 1 = opened), Interactable and BlockRaycasts parameters.

If you have menu script on every menu/panel just disable/enable that on open/close.

[image]

**Update:**

Typical uses of Canvas Group are:

- Fading in or out a whole window by adding a Canvas Group on the GameObject of the Window and control its Alpha property.
- Making a whole set of controls non-interactable (“grayed out”) by adding a Canvas Group to a parent GameObject and setting its Interactable property to false.
- Making one or more UI elements not block mouse events by placing a Canvas Group component on the element or one of its parents and setting its Block Raycasts property to false.

Other references:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbmjturGbAQ

https://github.com/Unitarian/Unity-Extensions/tree/master/Menus

Hope this helps

Comment: Each menu has it's own canvas component, but they all have different scripts on them. Would it be sufficient to increase performance to just deactivate the canvas instead of the gameobject? This way scripts can continue to run and e.g. animation components don't reset their variables.
Or is there an actual benefit to use the CanvasGroup component for this situation?

Comment: It is recommended to have one canvas on parent object as it will be getting ui Raycast etc. And CanvasGroup is specifically made to serve the menu objects as you can see from its exposed properties. If you dont want to disable your menu scripts just setup canvas group in Open()/Close() methods as I stated in answer.

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly: I should add a CanvasGroup to all individual menus (e.g. options menu) and whenever the options shouldn't be visible to the player, I just set Alpha, Interactable and BlocksRaycasts all to 0?
This seems weird to me, because usually you want to avoid transparencies when optimizing performance.

Comment: Thats right. This is not same as setting transparency of any object. Only reason you would want to use CanvasGroup is if your menu (main/option menu) have many children and enable/disable will force many components on children to do certain operations. (Like ScrollRect is the scary one performance wise). Check my updated answer for CanvasGroup's uses.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating interface like

```
public interface IOpenable
    {

        bool IsClosed { get; set; }

        void OpenWindow();
    }
}
```

then make every element subscribe to some controller and that controller can handle everything like so

```
public class MenuController: MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<IOpenable> MenuList;

    void Awake()
    {
        MenuList = new List<IOpenable>();
    }
    public void TryClose(IOpenable sender)
    {
        foreach (var i in MenuList)
        {
            if (!i.IsClosed && !sender.Equals(i))
                        i.OpenWindow();         
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can try to close all other windows you don't need while opening a new one. This is just a rough idea but it seems clean and fast for me.

Comment: An interface like that could unify the opening and closing process a bit, but it doesn't stop the inconveniences in the first place. The major question here is, whether the deactivation is actually worth something, or does every clipped canvas just take 1 cancelled render call or something (I don't know the details about how that works) and basically produces no cost at runtime?

Comment: according to [link]https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/best-practices/fill-rate-canvases-and-input it is recommented to disable gameobjects that hold any canvas or ui object if we don't need them. I'm myself not aware for now how batching works for canvases but if the same as for meshes then you are probably calling 1 drawcall per canvas. But you can check it easily with profiler tool in Unity.

Comment: I have scripts on the objects, which I don't want to deactivate though. That's why I'm looking for a solution to e.g. disable just the canvas component on the hidden menus, but as I learnt now, not every menu should have it's own canvas.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Unity optimization document](https://create.unity3d.com/Unity-UI-optimization-tips), disabling the Canvas (not deactivating its Game Object!) is the best way to hide it.

It's cheap to disable and re-enable the Canvas.